# Не работает addListener в libGDX

Tags: libgdx, listener, imagebutton

Делаю приложение, хотел добавить кнопки **ImageButton**. Я не понимаю, почему не работает мой **addListener()**, хотя кнопка

1. Инициализирована
2. Добавлена в сцену
3. Отрисовывается верно

В конструкторе класса **MainGameScreen** создал экземпляры и установил **setInputProcessor** на текущую сцену:

```
_viewport = new ScreenViewport();
_stage = new Stage();
iniatilizeButtons();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(_stage);
```

В функции **iniatilizeButtons()** описан стиль кнопки, тут же кнопка добавлена в сцену и определен **addListener()**:

```
buttonTextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/joystick/joystick.atlas");

skin = new Skin();
skin.addRegions(buttonTextureAtlas);

buttonRightStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
buttonRightStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("touchBackground");
buttonRightStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("touchKnob");
buttonRightStyle.checked = skin.getDrawable("touchKnob");

buttonRight = new ImageButton(buttonRightStyle);
buttonRight.setPosition(20, 20);
buttonRight.setTransform(true);
buttonRight.setScale(0.001f*Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

_stage.addActor(buttonRight);

buttonRight.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Button Pressed");
        hide();
    }
});
```

При вызове **render()** делаю это:

```
_stage.act(delta);
_stage.draw();
```

Немного проясню, нажатие кнопки и ее отпускание не выводит "Button Pressed", который я указал в touchUp(). Я добавлял и touchDown(), и clicked(), но они тоже ничего не выводят при нажатии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вызвать `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(_stage);` не в конструкторе, а в методе `create()`

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработало, только у меня был метод show(), в котором я заменил ранее установленный Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(_multiplexer); на ваш. Еще раз спасибо.